React/HTML Editable Div being unfocused after content changed
I am trying to create a text input that automatically wraps. The default input and textarea blocks did not work for the styling I wanted so I resorted to using a contenteditable div. Everything works perfectly fine on desktop but fails on mobile. There is an initial placeholder text that is cleared when the user focuses the div. This works properly on mobile and the keyboard pops up but the div is then unfocused and the keyboard does not type into the div. If you click the div again, it then types. How can I fix this? I attached the code below.
const CustomTextEntry = ({placeholder}) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState(placeholder);

    const onFocus = (e) => {
        if (e.target.textContent == placeholder)
            e.target.textContent = "";
        setText(e.target.textContent);
    };

    const onBlur = (e) => {
        if (e.target.textContent == "")
            e.target.textContent = placeholder;
        setText(e.target.textContent);
    }

    const onInput = (e) => {
        if (e.nativeEvent.data == '\n')
            e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <div
            contentEditable="true"
            suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onBeforeInput={onInput}
        >
            {placeholder}
        </div>
    )
}


I just tried the component you provided but the problem you described was not reproduced. On tapping the placeholder message the content disappears, the keyboard pops up and when I type the div is populated.
Device: Pixel 6
Browsers tried: Chrome, Firefox

This seems to be an IOS only issue but it can be solved by using a combination of onFocus (for desktops) and onTouchStart (for mobile).
